# Is there a way to get a response back from Stripe API webhooks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am currently working on a React website and NodeJS API that implements the Stripe API to allow payments. The user can subscribe to 3 different plans and get different access depending on the chosen plan.

I have already set up the webhook endpoint URL in my stripe account and there is no problem about that. I am getting webhooks and I manage my database depending on the event type.

My problem is that I want to update my frontend as soon as a payment succeeded for example when the `invoice.payment_succeeded` is triggered. But the fact that this is a webhook to a POST route, I can not send back a responses to my client. I was wondering if there is actually a way to send back data after a webhook.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: What sort of connection, if any, do you have between your client and your server? (I mean in general, not for the stripe case specifically)

Comment: What do you mean by "sort of connection"? I have a rest api (nodejs) listening on a certain port and a reactjs frontend that makes api requests with axios

Comment: For example, a websocket connection.

Comment: Ok so I have to implement websockets to be able to get real time updates then. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a `web socket connection`.

1. send data to the web socket as soon as you receive `invoice.payment_succeeded` from the webhook.
2. implement socket client in the react app to listen to the data send from the server.